# Simple User defined functions from VBA dont work in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create some User Defined Functions but they all result in #Value! Error.

My Macro has been enabled. I even added the Application.Volatile (as suggested on some posts). Nothing works.

These are some of my statements, they all result in the same error. 
1)

```
Function Excer1(x)
    Application.Volatile
    Excer1(x) = x ^ 2 - 3
End Function
```

2)

```
Function Excer2(x)
    Application.Volatile
    Excer2(x) = Sqr(2 * x ^ 2) + 2 * x
End Function
```

3)

```
Function Excer3a(x1, x2)
    Excer3a(x1, x2) = Log(x2 / x1)
End Function
```

Comment: How exactly are you calling them?

Comment: Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This 
will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the variable 
declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant/object type. Using **Option Explicit** is 
widely considered 'best practice'.

Comment: Thanks for this advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return lines are incorrect - the parentheses and arguments should not be included:

```
Function Excer1(x)
    Application.Volatile
    Excer1 = x ^ 2 - 3
End Function

Function Excer2(x)
    Application.Volatile
    Excer2 = Sqr(2 * x ^ 2) + 2 * x
End Function

Function Excer3a(x1, x2)
    Excer3a = Log(x2 / x1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You were **very** close:

```
Function Excer1(x)
    Application.Volatile
    Excer1 = x ^ 2 - 3
End Function
'2)

Function Excer2(x)
    Application.Volatile
    Excer2 = Sqr(2 * x ^ 2) + 2 * x
End Function
'3)

Function Excer3a(x1, x2)
    Excer3a = Log(x2 / x1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I should have not included the variable (in this case "x") when defining the functions:

Corrected versions:

```
Function Excer1(x)
Application.Volatile
Excer1 = x ^ 2 - 3
End Function

Function Excer2(x)
Application.Volatile
Excer2 = Sqr(2 * x ^ 2) + 2 * x
End Function

Function Excer3a(x1, x2)
Excer3a = Log(x2 / x1)
End Function
```